# undefined index warning in PHP for LDAP attribute / associative array

Tags: php, ldap

I have following function

```
function getContactInfo1() {   
        $filter = "(cn="."CRALT - Admins".")"; 

        $result = ldap_search($this->con, "OU=Distribution Groups,OU=Groups,DC=rim,DC=net", $filter, array('managedBy','msExchCoManagedByLink'));  
            $entry = ldap_get_entries($this->con, $result); 
            return array('owner'=>$entry[0]['managedBy'][0],'altOwner'=>$entry[0]['msExchCoManagedByLink'][0]);  

        }
```

when i try to call it, it gives me following error: -

```
C:\>php C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\1.php
Hitesh Thakur<hr>PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  managedBy in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs
\cralt_dev\LDAPutils.class.php on line 28
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  msExchCoManagedByLink in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\cral
t_dev\LDAPutils.class.php on line 28
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you requested the attribute 'managedBy' the array returned only contains the key 'managedby' in lowercase.

As array-keys in PHP are case-sensitive the key 'managedBy' does not exist.

Use strtolower on your requested attribute names and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error but a Notice saying that the array index is not existing.

You can avoid this by checking for the value before using it.

```
$entry = ldap_get_entries($this->con, $result); 
$owner = isset($entry[0]['managedBy']) ? $entry[0]['managedBy'][0] : '';
$altOwner = isset($entry[0]['msExchCoManagedByLink']) ? $entry[0]['msExchCoManagedByLink'][0] : '';
return array('owner'=>$owner,'altOwner'=>$altOwner);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it still gives the Undefined index:  managedBy error.

Comment: On the same line number?

Answer (score 0):

You can set error reporting at the begining of your php file.

```
error_reporting(0);
```